# What happens with classes of imported ontologies when generating Java code from it?

Tags: java, generator, owl, protege

I am trying to generate Java code from an ontology using the java code generating tool in Protege. The ontology I want to generate the code from imports another ontology. In the resulting generated code it seems to me like the java classes and interfaces corresponding with the Ontology classes in the imported ontology are missing.
The strange thing is, that the code generating tool needs the imported ontologies to be specified correctly in the .owl files to be able to run. So somehow the code generator reads them but doesn't generate code from it.
Is there an easy way to fix this? Or am I completely missing something?

Comment: I needed to generate the java code as well and tested this. The code generated for the upper ontology and the original ontology seems to be the same. Could you please elaborate.